# Query for associated Sequel models based on attributes in join table

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

Given `Sequel::Model` Items and Stores, joined through `Listings`, I would like to find `Items` and their associated `Stores` based on attributes of the listing.

```
DB.create_table? :items
  primary_key :id
end

DB.create_table? :stores
  primary_key :id
end

DB.create_table? :listings
  foreign_key :store_id
  foreign_key :item_id
  TrueClass :active, null: true
  String :name
end

class Item < Sequel::Model
  many_to_many :stores, join_table: :listings
end

class Store < Sequel::Model
  many_to_many :items, join_table: :listings
end

class Listing < Sequel::Model
end
```

I'm able to use `.association_join` and a `.where` clause to do this (shown below), but (A) I'm not sure if this is correct (B) it yields a result with props from both joined tables and (C) Calling `#stores` on a resulting `Item` results in another query.

```
Item.association_join(:stores).where(active: true, name: 'Sears').eager(:stores).first()
```

My end goal is an **dataset** of `Item`s that will eagerly load `#stores`.

What's the best way to approach doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way I've found I can do this is:

```
Listing.eager(item: :stores).where(active: true).all
```

This results in three queries up-front, but the entire chain of associations I'm interested in is loaded. Then I collect the items out of the array of Listings.

Also unsure if this is The Right Way.